# Create and Send JSON to MVC Action with multiple ICollection<anotherModel>

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, model, master-detail

I have a Master Detail Form. My master entity model is `Person` and my detail models are `ContactInfo` and `AddressInfo`. My `Person` model is like this:

```
public System.Guid PersonID { get; set; }
public int PersonTypeID { get; set; }
public string PersonFamily { get; set; }
public string PersonName { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> GenderID { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<AddressInfo> AddressInfoes { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ContactInfo> ContactInfoes { get; set; }
```

And Also My ContactInfo model is like this:

```
public System.Guid ContactInfoID { get; set; }
public System.Guid PersonID { get; set; }
public int ContactInfoTypeID { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.Guid> CountryDivisionID { get; set; }
public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

public virtual CountryDivision CountryDivision { get; set; }
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
```

I create my JSON and Post from Master Detail form like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: actionUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, i never succeeded to build correct format of JSON to cast correctly and always my `Person model` can't fill `ContactInfos collection` and always my model is without `ContactInfos`.

My Action is like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person model)
{
   ...
}
```

And finally my problem; Create Action can not cast `ContactInfos` in my `Person model`.
Posted JSON which my action receives is like this:

```
{"model":
    "PersonID":"e715b7a2-d349-4239-af12-c9037bdf4bee",
    "PersonName":"Jack",
    "PersonFamily":"Stivenssen",
    "GenderID":"1",
    "BirthDate":"",
    "Email":"d@iv.com",
    "Description":"this is a tet",
    "ContactInfos":[
        {"ContactInfoID":"de2c0de1-9297-4885-9882-44ae210ae6f0",
        "PersonID":"e715b7a2-d349-4239-af12-c9037bdf4bee",
        "ContactInfoTypeID":3,
        "CountryDivisionTitle":"Amity",
        "CountryDivisionID":"9fbd3616-47ae-4608-992e-1e2d0a51d2e9",
        "IsActive":"false"},
        {"ContactInfoID":"7f9a44d3-0532-4976-99e9-017cb59d22cc",
        "PersonID":"e715b7a2-d349-4239-af12-c9037bdf4bee",
        "ContactInfoTypeID":2,"ContactInfoTypeTitle":"Office",
        "CountryDivisionTitle":"Boston",
        "CountryDivisionID":"ea0b1a1b-a0c5-46b3-85c1-62bee4d6278e",
        {"ContactInfoID":"b3dfe0da-dc0c-48d8-8a07-8438e9149ddd",
        "PersonID":"e715b7a2-d349-4239-af12-c9037bdf4bee",
        "ContactInfoTypeID":1,
        "ContactInfoTypeTitle":"Mobile",
        "CountryDivisionTitle":"",
        "CountryDivisionID":"",
        "IsActive":"false"}
        ],
    "AddressInfos":[]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, in your Person entity you have navigation properties called "ContactInfoes" and "AddressInfoes" but in the JSON you're passing to controller you have "ContactInfos" and "AddressInfos". Try fixing the typo as MVC default model binder cannot bind your collection data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @George and @timothyclifford for your comment and answer respectively.
Unfortunately, the answer was shamefully easy which took two days of mine to be find.
Nobody including me have noticed that name of `ContactInfo` collection in my `Person` model is: `ContactInfoes` with **es** at the end not `ContactInfos`.
Yes guys, the problem was a syntax mismatch nor `IList<>` property type nor `{"model"` name presence at the beginning of the JSON, no offense.(i have spent two days to find this ridiculous problem, and surely if you were in my shoes would find it faster than me. ;) )

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @George in comments, you have a typo in your AddressInfo and ContactInfo properties. Fix this and also change these to IList rather than ICollection:

```
public virtual ICollection<AddressInfo> AddressInfos { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ContactInfo> ContactInfos { get; set; }
```

to

```
public virtual IList<AddressInfo> AddressInfos { get; set; }
public virtual IList<ContactInfo> ContactInfos { get; set; }
```

The JSON you're posting looks good however you're wrapping it in a `model` property. You need to remove this so you're JSON looks like:

```
{
    "PersonID":"e715b7a2-d349-4239-af12-c9037bdf4bee",
    "PersonName":"Jack",
    "PersonFamily":"Stivenssen",
    "GenderID":"1",
    "BirthDate":"",
    "Email":"d@iv.com",
    "Description":"this is a tet",
    "ContactInfos":[
        {"ContactInfoID":"de2c0de1-9297-4885-9882-44ae210ae6f0",
        "PersonID":"e715b7a2-d349-4239-af12-c9037bdf4bee",
        "ContactInfoTypeID":3,
        "CountryDivisionTitle":"Amity",
        "CountryDivisionID":"9fbd3616-47ae-4608-992e-1e2d0a51d2e9",
        "IsActive":"false"},
        {"ContactInfoID":"7f9a44d3-0532-4976-99e9-017cb59d22cc",
        "PersonID":"e715b7a2-d349-4239-af12-c9037bdf4bee",
        "ContactInfoTypeID":2,"ContactInfoTypeTitle":"Office",
        "CountryDivisionTitle":"Boston",
        "CountryDivisionID":"ea0b1a1b-a0c5-46b3-85c1-62bee4d6278e",
        {"ContactInfoID":"b3dfe0da-dc0c-48d8-8a07-8438e9149ddd",
        "PersonID":"e715b7a2-d349-4239-af12-c9037bdf4bee",
        "ContactInfoTypeID":1,
        "ContactInfoTypeTitle":"Mobile",
        "CountryDivisionTitle":"",
        "CountryDivisionID":"",
        "IsActive":"false"}
        ],
    "AddressInfos":[]
}
```